# Verifying in-app-billing purchase on my server with php

Tags: java, android, eclipse

So after a couple of days I finally got in-app-billing to work and communicate with the Google Servers. Now, i'm trying to implement in-app-billing so it would communicate and verify the transaction on my server.

I understand that the most secure model of this would be

`Client sends request to Google Play >> Google Play sends signed key to client >> client sends key to server >> server validates >> sends back a session token.`

However, I am currently stuck on where I would be implementing the client sending to the server. I have SSL enabled on my servers so I can securely communicate. Is there anywhere specifically in the sample Dungeons application where I could add into a pre-existing method the sending of my credentials to my server? Also is there a way I can get the package name, signature key from the google servers response and send it?

Also, is there any pre-existing code or tutorial showing how to validate the information sent by google?

Comment: This has been asked many times, there is even an open source project on Google Code that does this using PHP.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov Yes i've seen numerous amounts of posts about it, i've been trying to find that Google Code. Could you please redirect me to it?

Comment: First and only hit in the list: http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/

Comment: This library does not (yet) support verifying purchases made via Google Play's In-app Billing.

Comment: Same idea, you just need to some work to connect it.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. There really is no difference between License Verification and In-App-Billing Verification. I guess I judged a book by its color too fast. I'll be sure to post separately the revised code.